# State property immune from local taxation?

Tags: tax-law, new-hampshire, immunity

I know that Federal property is generally immune from local taxes, but what about property owned by the state? Is that just a matter of state law? Is there a term for this kind of immunity because I can't find it using standard searches.

Jurisdiction: New Hampshire

Comment: It is a matter of state law, probably in the statute that authorizes the property tqx in the first pace. Normally, it would be called a property tax exemption. There is probably no case law on point.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, property owned by governments, including  state governments, is generally exempt from property taxes in the US. (A list of the exemptions as of 2000 is available [here](https://www.civicfed.org/civic-federation/publications/property-tax-exemptions-overview-state-constiutional-and-statutory-pro).)

The governments that are exempt in New Hampshire are listed in [Ch 72 §23](http://www.gencourt.state.nh.us/rsa/html/V/72/72-23.htm) of the New Hampshire Statutes, *Real Estate and Personal Property Tax Exemption.*" These include the state, cities, towns, and school or village districts.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that municipalities generally have authority to tax only because that authority is delegated to them by the state.